# Crear ejecutable con python3 de varios archivos en diversas carpetas

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller

He realizado un programa en python3 creando varios modulos y guardandolos en diversas carpeta para una mejor organización. Al correrlo desde consola no hay problemas. Se me delplega la ventana realizada con pyqt5 y trabaja correctamente. Sin embargo al tratar de realizar como ejecutable utilizando pyinstaller me crea correctamente pero no se ejecuta el programa. Trata de abrirlo y luego termina rapidamente.Me pueden ayudar con este problema o aconsejar una mejor forma de realizar un ejecutable?
La estrucutra de los archivos es de la siguiente y el archivo con el inicio del programa es main.py:

```
     carpeta principal|
                      |main.py
                      |lib|
                          |modulo1.py
                          |...
                      |lib2|
                           |modulopyqt.py
                           |...
                      |config|
                             |archivo1.py
                             |...
                      |vars|
                           |archivo2.cvs
                           |...
```

Comment: Si sucede eso al crear el exe, generalmente se muestra un mensaje de error de Python. Lo que podría estar pasando es que se cierre la ventana de cmd antes de que puedas ver error. Para ver el error prueba con abrir el simbolo del sistema (asumo que usas Windows) y escribe en el input "[el directorio de tu exe]/archivo.exe" y si muestra algo agregalo en la pregunta por favor (en forma de texto claro).

Comment: Hola. Muchas gracias con eso pude verificar el error. Resulta que no me estaba tomando python3 sino python 2.7.. Desistale python2.7 y deje solo el python3.9  y con eso lo solucione. Gracias.